# What were the original purpose(s) of Doc Ock's auxiliary gadgets in his mechanical tentacles?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, spider-man-2, doctor-octopus

In the Sam Raimi-directed film *Spider-Man 2,* Doctor Octavius creates his iconic harness of mechanical tentacles for the purpose of manipulating and controlling his [fusion experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p66AWyzFIec).

In addition to the claws, we see that they contain auxiliary devices/gadgets, a few of which we can clearly see the purpose and use for, such as cameras (which we see [later in the film](https://youtu.be/L1s-PVl3k5c?t=38) give him a greater sense of his environment), and a smaller set of claws that he uses to handle smaller items (such as the tritium that he used as the fuel source of his experiment).

In addition to these, we also see a couple other devices that he uses during his fights with Spider-Man.  He has a set of daggers that can extend from the claws that we see him try to [use](https://youtu.be/L1s-PVl3k5c?t=259) at least [twice](https://youtu.be/du9StHQYGGs?t=113) against Spider-Man as weapons, and we also see him utilize some sort of smaller tentacle extention that he uses to bind people that he abducts (such as when he took [Aunt May](https://youtu.be/L1s-PVl3k5c?t=113) and [Mary Jane](https://youtu.be/ec8X1AoBxKI?t=159) as hostages).

I don't recall any moments during the film that indicate that these particular devices were added after the initial experiment.  Given the manipulative nature of the tentacles' AI, it seems unlikely to me that they would be open to any changes, especially if adding any upgrades would have required them to be placed in a potentially vulnerable state (as Octavius initially had a notoriously-hostile attitude towards them after he regained consciousness).  As a result, while I could be wrong, based on the available evidence I can only assume that these features were a part of the harness the entire time; and I haven't been able to find any sources that specify their originally-intended purpose(s).  [Many sources](http://spiderman-films.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Octopus_(Alfred_Molina)) make [no mention](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Octopus_(Spider-Man_Films)#Bank_Showdown) of them [at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Octopus); and at best, they get barely more than a [passing mention](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Otto_Octavius#Powers_and_Abilities).

Did these auxiliary devices have any potential use for his experiments that we didn't see on film?

Comment: See...this is the issue *" I can only assume that they were a part of the harness the entire time"*...that's your assumption. You seem to want to *prove a negative*.

Comment: Exactly. Why couldn't they have been added off-screen?

Comment: Didn't say that they _couldn't_ have been added off-screen.  I'm just saying that I saw no evidence of it.  If such evidence exists, it would qualify as an answer to the question.  In any case, I neglected to mention that I actually considered this to be an unlikely scenario given the manipulative nature of the tentacles' AI (as I imagine they would likely be resistant to change, especially if it would have required placing them in a vulnerable state to add the upgrades, as Octavius was originally hostile to them after he regained consciousness).  For clarity's sake, I'll add that now.